# php for each giving invalid argument error

Tags: php, jquery, implode

I am trying to delete multiple rows based on the checked checkboxes, I am passing the value of each checkbox to ajax request on the `php` page I am using `implode` to get individual ids however I am getting worning 
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. 
can someone help me out?

**js**

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() { 
   var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete.php",
    data: {dtar: 'dms', mxd: val},
    cache: false,
    success: function(response)
    {  
      $("#print").html(response);
    }
});
```

});

**php**

```
if(isset($_POST["dtar"]) && $_POST["dtar"] == 'dms'){
   $id =  $_POST['mxd']; 
    $ms_id = implode(",", $id);
   if(!empty($id)){
    $stmt = $db->prepare(".....");
    $stmt->bind_param(...);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     foreach  ($ms_id as $id) {
    //do something
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Well, `implode()` _never_ returns an array, but a string. You cannot iterate over a string with `forach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have done this..

```
$ms_id = implode(",", $id);
```

Your `$ms_id` is now a string and you are doing this below

```
foreach  ($ms_id as $id) {
```

.. You **cannot** loop through a string and that's the reason behind this problem.

Loop through the `$id` variable instead , since it is an array..

```
foreach  ($id as $idvalue ) {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) check $ms_id is an array by

```
if (is_array($ms_id )) {
  foreach  ($ms_id as $id) {
    //do something
    }
}
```

2) while($row $result->fetch_assoc()){ //i think u are missing '=' sign after $row

3) As far i know ther is now fetch_assoc() function in PDO 
 instead

```
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

just use $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: thanks. I am actually using mysqli prepared statements for the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

you are converting array in string using `implode()` so use a check for array using `is_array()` and aslo you have wrong condition in your while

```
if(isset($_POST["dtar"]) && $_POST["dtar"] == 'dms'){
       $id =  $_POST['mxd']; 
       // $ms_id = implode(",", $id);
       if(!empty($id)){
        $stmt = $db->prepare(".....");
        $stmt->bind_param(...);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if(is_array($id)) {
           foreach  ($id as $mid) {
             //do something
           }
        }
       }
     }
```